# OpenGL Vertex Array, Matrix Pointer?

Tags: opengl, opentk

I wrote a piece of code a year back for rendering editable 2D `Shapes` using C# + OpenTK. Each `shape` has its own vertices and editing the `Shape` directly changes the vertex values.

I have a `CollectVertices()` in the display_callback_func which iterates all the `Shapes` and combine the vertex information in big arrays and draw them at once using the snippet below:

```
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);

// draw fills (triangles)
GL.ColorPointer<byte>(3, ColorPointerType.UnsignedByte, 0, fillColor);
GL.VertexPointer<double>(2, VertexPointerType.Double, 0, fillArray);
GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Triangles, 0, fillArray.Length / 2);

// draw lines
GL.ColorPointer<byte>(3, ColorPointerType.UnsignedByte, 0, lineColor);
GL.VertexPointer<double>(2, VertexPointerType.Double, 0, lineArray);
GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.Lines, 0, lineArray.Length / 2);

GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
```

One year later today, I want to introduce a new `struct Transform` to the `Shape` object. It will contain a `Vector2 Center` and `Matrix Orientation`. Editing the `Shape` now will change values in `Transform` instead (although scaling will still be done on vertex data, as it should logically be so).

What is a neat way, with minimal changes to the above snippet, to include the transformation matrix?

Comment: How bad would it be to break up the drawArrays calls to one call per object, such that you can set the matrix as a uniform before each call? That's the only sensible thing I can think of to do.

Comment: @Tim It's not entirely bad, but I was hoping to see if there is a way without the need to abandon the whole `CollectVertices()` and re-do everything per `Shape`.

Comment: A thought might be to just include an index with each vertex, and then use that index to do lookup into an array of matrices, but I have a gut feeling that would perform worse than the alternative. Might be worth trying though.

Comment: I suppose you could put the matrices into a texture and use the index there :-) but that feels terribly hacky and I'm not sure you'd be able to sleep at night afterwards.  But then now I think about it, if it's a 4x4 matrix, it's 4 vec 4's.  Now you can use instancing and setup a second vertex stream that contains the per-shape matrices.  Google for instancing to see how to do it (I know about it, but haven't tried it yet).

Comment: A matrix `Orientation` sounds like a rotation? Perhaps you could pack a quaternion into a 4 Byte float and recalculate the matrix in the vertex shader?

Comment: Is there a GL command to pack the floats for every Shape into a single array and make DrawArray aware of it? Like how VertexPoint and ColorPointer works?

Comment: You mean [glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml). Seems like one generic attribute is capable of transporting one vec4, so for a general 4x4 matrix, you need 4 attributes.